# How to query through array of objects

Tags: sails.js

I have a sails application which has an "experience" and "media" model. Experience has a media attribute which is an array, and contains denormalized media objects.

I am currently trying to figure out how to query experience so that I see all of the experiences with a media with a specific id.

What this looks like:

```
{
   ...
   "media": [
     {
        ...
        "id": "10"
     }
   ],
   ...
   "id": "1"
},
{
   ...
   "media": [
     {
     ... 
     "id": "20"
     }
   ],
   ...
   "id": "2"
}
```

How would I get all experiences that contain media with id=10?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, the query would look like `GET experience?where={"media.id":"10"}`

Comment: You can't do that in sails query because when you use find({'media.id':10}), then sails treat media as Model not attribute as nesting/embedding is not supported in sails.